# How to write this into php code? Alt of the Image

Tags: php, xpath, xpath-2.0

How to write this into code please?

if the alt of the image is "your alt here" then its 1.

Here is the code that i made.

```
public function getSiteAdvisor($domain)
        {
            try
            {
                $callback_url = "https://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/site/default.aspx?url=" . $domain;
```

```
            $curl_response = $this->curl->get($callback_url);

            if ($curl_response->headers['Status-Code'] == "200") {

                libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
                $this->dom_doc->loadHTML($curl_response);
                libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

                $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom_doc);
                $tmp = $xpath->query('/html/body//div[@class="threeFourth"]//img/@alt')->item(0);
```

I don't know how to code the 'alt' of the image. 
I add some code but not sure if this is correct.

if ($tmp->hasAttribute('src')) {

`$tmp = $tmp->getAttribute('src');

                    if (stripos($tmp, "Minimal") !== false) {        
                        $siteadvisor_rating = 1;
                    } elseif (stripos($tmp, "Moderate") !== false) {   
                        $siteadvisor_rating = 2;
                    } elseif (stripos($tmp, "High") !== false) {     
                        $siteadvisor_rating = 3;
                    } else {
                        $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
                }

            } else {
                $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
            }

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => array(
                    'siteadvisor' => (int)$siteadvisor_rating
                )
            );
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        return $response;       
    }`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by using this:

```
 if ($tmp->hasAttribute('src')) {
```

`$tmp = $tmp->getAttribute('alt');

                if (stripos($tmp, "Minimal") !== false) {        
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 1;
                } elseif (stripos($tmp, "Moderate") !== false) {   
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 2;
                } elseif (stripos($tmp, "High") !== false) {     
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 3;
                } else {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
                }
            } else {
                $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
            }

        } else {
            $siteadvisor_rating = 0;`